# Creating an object-oriented router class in PHP

Tags: php, object-oriented, mvc, url-routing, .htaccess

On my way to learn OOP, I am developing a little CMS using the MVC pattern. I would like to have some feedback about my router class, mostly about if I am correctly using OOP.

Right now, I have a .htaccess file redirecting requests to an index.php file, both of them in the root directory of the project.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|txt|otf|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Then I run this router class to get the requested URL and call to the correct controller class and method:

Router.php

```
<?php
namespace Core;

use Controller;

if ( !class_exists( 'Router' ) ) {

    class Router {

        /**
        *   Allowed URL patterns
        * @var Array
        */
        private $routes;

        /**
        *   Allowed prefixs for URLs
        * @var String
        */
        private $prefix;

        /**
        *   Requested URL
        * @var String
        */
        private $url;

        /**
        *   Run the router
        */
        public function run() {
            $this->set_url();
            $this->dispatch();
        }

        /**
        *   Set a new route
        */
        public function set($route) {

            if ( is_array($route) ) {
                foreach ( $route as $regex => $control ) {
                    $this->routes[$regex] = $control;
                }
            } else {
                $default_routes = $this->generate_default_routes($route);
                foreach ( $default_routes as $regex => $control ) {
                    $this->routes[$regex] = $control;
                }
            }

        }

        /**
        *   get routes
        */
        public function get_routes() {

            return $this->routes;

        }

        /**
        *   Default routes
        */
        public function generate_default_routes($object) {
            ucfirst($object);
            return $routes = array(
                '~^\/'.$object.'s\/$~'               => $object.'sController@list_all',
                '~^\/'.$object.'\/(\d+)\/$~'         => $object.'sController@display',
                '~^\/admin\/'.$object.'s\/$~'               => $object.'sController@list_all',
                '~^\/admin\/'.$object.'\/new\/$~'           => $object.'sController@create',
                '~^\/admin\/'.$object.'\/(\d+)\/edit\/$~'   => $object.'sController@edit',
                '~^\/admin\/'.$object.'\/(\d+)\/delete\/$~' => $object.'sController@delete',
            );
        }

        /**
        *   set routes prefix
        */
        public function set_prefix($prefix) {

            foreach ( $prefix as $regex => $control ) {
                $this->prefix[$regex] = $control;
            }

        }

        /**
        *   get requested url
        */
        public function set_url() {

            $url = isset($_GET['uri']) ? '/' . $_GET['uri'] . '/' : '';
            $this->url = urldecode(trim($url));

        }

        /**
        *   get requested url
        */
        public function get_url() {

            return $this->url;

        }

        /**
        *   Call the correct controller class and method
        */
        public function dispatch() {

            //find if the url match any specified route
            $args = $this->find_match($this->url, $this->routes);

            //set data
            $action = isset($args['action']) ? $args['action'] : '';
            $id = isset($args['id']) ? $args['id'] : '';
            $admin = isset($args['admin']) ? $args['admin'] : '';

            if ( !empty($action) ) {

                if ( preg_match('/@/', $action) ) {

                    list($object, $method, $params) = $this->get_call_params($action, $id, $admin);
                    call_user_func_array(array($object,$method), $params);

                } else {
                    echo "invalid method supplied for the route: " . $this->url;
                }

            } else {
                echo "invalid route: " . $this->url;
            }

        }

        /**
        *   find if the requested URL match any of the allowed route patterns
        */
        public function find_match($uri, $routes) {

            $args = array();

            foreach ( $routes as $regex => $controller) {
                if ( preg_match($regex, $uri) ) {
                    $args['action'] = $controller;

                    if ( preg_match('/([a-zA-Z]+)\/(\d+)/', $uri) ) {
                        preg_match('/(\d+)/', $uri, $matches);
                        $args['id'] = $matches[0];
                    }

                    if ( preg_match('~^\/admin/~', $uri) ) {
                        preg_match('~^\/admin/~', $uri, $matches);
                        $args['admin'] = $matches[0];
                    }
                }
            }

            return $args;

        }

        /**
        *   Prepare data for correct dispatching
        */
        public function get_call_params($action, $id, $admin) {

            //split action into controller and method
            $actions = explode('@', $action);
            list($controller, $method) = $actions;

            if ( !empty($admin) ) {
                $prefix = $this->prefix['admin'];
            } else {
                $prefix = $this->prefix['default'];
            }

            $controller = ucfirst($controller);

            //instantiate the controller object
            $class = 'Controller\\' . $controller;
            $object = new $class($action, $prefix);

            //set params array
            $params = array();
            $params[] = $id;

            return array($object, $method, $params);

        }


    }

}


?>
```

I use this routes.php file as routes configuration file, where I set the allowed paths objects for the paths patterns and the prefixes.

routes.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Allowed url pattern prefixes
 */
$router->set_prefix( array( 'default'   => '' ) );
$router->set_prefix( array( 'admin'     => 'admin' ) );


/**
 * Set up allowed URLs
 */
$router->set( array ( '/\//'    => 'BaseController@index' ) );
$router->set( array ( '/login/' => 'Auth@login' ) );
$router->set( array ( '/logout/'    => 'Auth@logout' ) );
$router->set( array ( '/admin/' => 'BaseController@admin_index' ) );
$router->set('page');
$router->set('user');
$router->set('cat');
$router->set('tag');
$router->set('media');
$router->set('option');

?>
```

Comment: Doing `if ( !class_exists( 'Router' ) )` is bad for opcode caching. Instead use `require_once` to only load the php file that defines the class once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't repeat yourself**

```
    public function set($route) {

        if ( is_array($route) ) {
            foreach ( $route as $regex => $control ) {
                $this->routes[$regex] = $control;
            }
        } else {
            $default_routes = $this->generate_default_routes($route);
            foreach ( $default_routes as $regex => $control ) {
                $this->routes[$regex] = $control;
            }
        }

    }
```

can and should probably be written without duplicated logic :

```
        $routes = is_array($route) ? $route : $this->generate_default_routes($route);
        foreach ( $default_routes as $regex => $control ) {
            $this->routes[$regex] = $control;
        }
```

Similarly :

```
        if ( !empty($admin) ) {
            $prefix = $this->prefix['admin'];
        } else {
            $prefix = $this->prefix['default'];
        }
```

could become :

```
        $prefix = $this->prefix[empty($admin) : 'default' : 'admin'];
```

**Style**

You are a bit inconsistent in your vertical spacing. My personal point of view is that you don't need that many blank lines.